# ADFS 3.0 server with JS Client on dfiferent domains, Oauth2 Sign out no redirect

Tags: javascript, oauth-2.0, client, adfs3.0

We have an ADFS server setup on one domain:

```
ADFSSERVER.com/
```

and we have a javascript client set up on another domain

```
JavascriptClient.com/
```

We added the javascript client to the ADFS server using the `Add-Client` command in the powershell.

From here, we cann sign in using oauth 2 and obtain a token including claims.
The problem now is that we want the user to sign out from our app.

We have tried using the following url to sign out which works, but when we want to be able to redirect after sign out, when we specify the the redirect url (wreply=) in the query string, it never seems to work. We have tried everything

```
https://ADFSSERVER.coom/adfs/ls/?wa=wsignout1.0&wreply="https://JavascriptClient.com/" .
```

How can we redirect after sign out in ADFS 3.00 server 2012r2?
If they are on different domains, on different servers is this possible? 
If so, how is this acheived.

Any help would be greatly appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

"wa=wsignout" is WS-Fed not OAuth.

I don't believe sign-out was implemented in ADFS 3.0 for OAuth. It is implemented in ADFS 4.0.

"-EnableOAuthLogout

Enables the OAuth logout endpoint publishing in the OAuth discovery document. The OAuth logout endpoint logs out the current user from the ADFS. It does not support logging out a federated user from the federated identity provider. This parameter is only available with the Windows Update KB4019472 installed."

Answer (score 0):

ADFS 3.0 has OpenId Connect support (extension of OAuth 2). Check if there is a end_session_endpoint in the OpenID connect discovery endpoint defined https://ADFSSERVER/.well-known/openid-configuration see [OpenID connect session management](http://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-session-1_0.html#EndpointDiscovery)

Comment: ADFS 3.0 only supports OAuth not OIDC. You need ADFS 4.0 for that.